# What/Where is the hall of Ask Different inquisitors page?

Tags: discussion, support, site-promotion

On the recent [site-promotion page](http://www.thenewipadishere.com) was the following nugget:

> everyone who completes Level 1: Use Different and beyond will have
>   their gravatars honored in the hall of Ask Different inquisitors page.

What/Where is this located, or is this just the contest page itself?

Answer (score 2):

The hall is the main landing page as far as I can tell.

http://www.thenewipadishere.com/

Stack Exchange bought that domain and it's still up, so [Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.) or perhaps QEF?

Comment: I don't know enough about the history or organisation of the promotion to vote, but yes … we do see the gravatars of the winners *at* the page that mentions the *hall of Ask Different inquisitors* page. I'd vote for the puzzling wording to be removed from the page.

Comment: It's almost worth registering AskDifferentInquisitors.com...

Comment: It makes us sound like sith and jedi, no?